# Allow non-ssl connections: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed

Tags: java, android, ssl, swagger, codegen

Using java client generated codegen, I am receiving a handshake failed when trying to connect to my localhost which isn't SSL.  What do I specify in the Android code to allow?  The codegen is also using (okhttp:2.7.5):

```
04-13 09:21:28.874 14993-14993/gen_test.timnuwin.com.testapi D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
04-13 09:21:29.431 14993-14993/gen_test.timnuwin.com.testapi W/System.err: io.swagger.client.ApiException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
04-13 09:21:29.431 14993-14993/gen_test.timnuwin.com.testapi W/System.err:     at io.swagger.client.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:972)
04-13 09:21:29.432 14993-14993/gen_test.timnuwin.com.testapi W/System.err:     at io.swagger.client.api.DefaultApi.transferIntentHistoryWithHttpInfo(DefaultApi.java:380)
04-13 09:21:29.432 14993-14993/gen_test.timnuwin.com.testapi W/System.err:     at io.swagger.client.api.DefaultApi.transferIntentHistory(DefaultApi.java:365)
04-13 09:21:29.432 14993-14993/gen_test.timnuwin.com.testapi W/System.err:     at gen_test.timnuwin.com.testapi.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:41)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out codegen is prepending to the network protocol assuming it's *https* Updating this to http resolved the issue.